# GWT - RemoteService interface and Spring - how to get HttpSession?

Tags: spring, gwt, httpsession

I am using GWT (2.5) with RPC, Spring and Postgresql for my project.  My issue is about HttpSession handling . 
All queries to server are dispatched by Spring  (DispatchServlet) to my GwtController  (extends  RemoteServiceServlet) . 
The particular RemoteService is injected in the GwtController . It is easy to get the HttpSession inside the GwtContorller. 
In example by getThreadLocalRequest().getSession() or just from request.getSession(). 
My question is how to get HttpSession object inside the RemoteService ?

```
public class GwtRpcController extends RemoteServiceServlet {
……………
private RemoteService remoteService;
private Class remoteServiceClass;
………………

public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    …………
} 

public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {
    …………
}

public void setRemoteService(RemoteService remoteService) {
    …………….
}

}
```

My Interface - DataService which implements RemoteService

```
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

public Data getData(){

    !!!!! Here I want to get HttpSession !!!!!
    …………………………

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain a `ThreadLocal` in your `Servlet` and store there your current `Request`, then expose your `Request` with a static method.

```java
public class GwtRpcController extends RemoteServiceServlet {

  static ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> perThreadRequest = 
         new ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>();

  @Override
  public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {
    try {
      perThreadRequest.set(getThreadLocalRequest());
      return super.processCall(payload);
    } finally {
      perThreadRequest.set(null);
    }
  }

  public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return perThreadRequest.get();
  }
}


 public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {
    public Data getData(){
       HttpServletRequest request = GwtRpcController.getRequest();
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    }
 }
```